# Can I change the datatype of metadata

Tags: types, metadata, orange, predictive

Does someone know if you can change the datatype of metadata? I would like to predict the price of Airbnb stays. The price is depending on the room type and the location of the stay. Both features are marked as metadata. As a consequence I cannot see those features in my 'Feature Statistics' in Orange and cannot see the statistics for those features.

Comment: Hi Iyv, welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you include a copy of what you have tried, what you get, and what you wanted?

Comment: Hi @Eureka! Thanks for answering! I used the dataset on the following link (https://www.kaggle.com/dgomonov/new-york-city-airbnb-open-data). I would like to include a copy of what I have tried but I don't know how? Is there a possibility to send some screenshots? Now, I have changed the features 'Neighbourhood_group', 'Neighbourhood' and 'Room_type' in categorical data types instead of metadata as they are related with the price I want to predict ( and I have heard that you can't do statistics on metadata). Is this a possibility? Or can I not change it?